# TLS connection error in nodejs application

Tags: node.js, node-modules, node-red

I have a node js application which is making a post request to another application deployed on the same server. On making the post request I am getting the below error

```
 **Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
        at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (_tls_wrap.js:1299:19)
        at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:284:20)
        at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:201:15)
        at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1130:12)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:17)**
```

I understand that to make this work I have to enable SSL connection and provide server certificate which I have already done in node red.

[image: Node red SSLconfiguration]

I have used the below openssl command to generate crt file and private key

**req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privateKey.key -out certificate.crt**

Please let me know what mistake am I doing here which is preventing this from working

Comment: Are you trying to authenticate Node-RED to the other server using certificates?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the certificate.crt and privateKey.key to set up the https server in the other application and not doing TLS Client authentication.

You need to remove the Certificate and Private Key entries and upload the certificate.crt file as the CA Certificate. This will then be used to verify that the remote server is who they claim to be.

Comment: tried that but I still get the same error

Comment: Then I suspect the error is on the other end